# Standardized coefficients for lmer model

Tags: multi-level, mixed-models, lmer, coefficients

I used to use the code below to calculate standardized coefficients of a `lmer` model. However, with the new version of lme the structure of the returned object has changed.

How to adapt the function `stdCoef.lmer` to make it work with the new `lme4` version?

```
# Install old version of lme 4
install.packages("lme4.0", type="both",
                 repos=c("http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
                         getOption("repos")[["CRAN"]]))

# Load package
detach("package:lme4", unload=TRUE)
library(lme4.0)

# Define function to get standardized coefficients from an lmer
# See: https://github.com/jebyrnes/ext-meta/blob/master/r/lmerMetaPrep.R
stdCoef.lmer <- function(object) {
  sdy <- sd(attr(object, "y"))
  sdx <- apply(attr(object, "X"), 2, sd)
  sc <- fixef(object)*sdx/sdy
  #mimic se.ranef from pacakge "arm"
  se.fixef <- function(obj) attr(summary(obj), "coefs")[,2]
  se <- se.fixef(object)*sdx/sdy
  return(list(stdcoef=sc, stdse=se))
}

# Run model
fm0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

# Get standardized coefficients
stdCoef.lmer(fm0)

# Comparison model with prescaled variables
fm0.comparison <- lmer(scale(Reaction) ~ scale(Days) + (scale(Days) | Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer by @LeonardoBergamini works, but this one is more compact and understandable and only uses standard accessors — less likely to break in the future if/when the structure of the `summary()` output, or the internal structure of the fitted model, changes.

```
stdCoef.merMod <- function(object) {
  sdy <- sd(getME(object,"y"))
  sdx <- apply(getME(object,"X"), 2, sd)
  sc <- fixef(object)*sdx/sdy
  se.fixef <- coef(summary(object))[,"Std. Error"]
  se <- se.fixef*sdx/sdy
  return(data.frame(stdcoef=sc, stdse=se))
}
library("lme4")
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fixef(fm1)
## (Intercept)        Days 
##   251.40510    10.46729
stdCoef.merMod(fm1)
##               stdcoef      stdse
## (Intercept) 0.0000000 0.00000000
## Days        0.5352302 0.07904178
```

(This does give the same results as `stdCoef.lmer` in
@LeonardoBergamini's answer ...)

You can get partially scaled coefficients — scaled by 2 times the SD of x, but not scaled by SD(y), and not centred — using `broom.mixed::tidy` + `dotwhisker::by_2sd`:

```r
library(broom.mixed)
library(dotwhisker)
(fm1 
    |> tidy(effect="fixed") 
    |> by_2sd(data=sleepstudy) 
    |> dplyr::select(term, estimate, std.error)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

this should work:

```
stdCoef.lmer <- function(object) {
  sdy <- sd(attr(object, "resp")$y) # the y values are now in the 'y' slot 
  ###                                 of the resp attribute
  sdx <- apply(attr(object, "pp")$X, 2, sd) # And the X matriz is in the 'X' slot of the pp attr
  sc <- fixef(object)*sdx/sdy
  #mimic se.ranef from pacakge "arm"
  se.fixef <- function(obj) as.data.frame(summary(obj)[10])[,2] # last change - extracting 
  ##             the standard errors from the summary
  se <- se.fixef(object)*sdx/sdy
  return(data.frame(stdcoef=sc, stdse=se))
}
```